# need help for UIPickerView keyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview, xcode4.3

New to objective c and this maybe a simple error. I am trying to dismiss all 3 `UITextField` keyboard which i have for `UIPickerView`. Whereby the keyboard won't appear only the picker view would be shown. I did some research but can't figure it out. Here is the code for the .m file and it won't work.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    modeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(textField.tag==1){
        [modeArray addObject:@" bus "];
        [modeArray addObject:@" bus/mrt "];
        tbMode.inputView = pickerView;
        pickerView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
        if(textField.tag==2){
            [modeArray addObject:@" 300 "];
            [modeArray addObject:@" 400 "]; 
            [modeArray addObject:@" 500 "];
            tbWalkDist.inputView = pickerView;
            pickerView.hidden = NO;
        }
        else{
            if(textField.tag==3){
                [modeArray addObject:@" cheapest "];
                [modeArray addObject:@" fastest "];
                tbRouteOpt.inputView = pickerView;
                pickerView.hidden = NO;
            }
            else{
                pickerView.hidden=YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how should i dismiss the keyboard only showing the picker view? Using this line `[textField resignFirstResponder];` can i use to dimiss the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate all your text fields to the viewController and then use the method;

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField // called from textfield (keyboard) 
{
//... place your [textField resignFirstResponder]; logic here
}
```

Make sure you add the text view delegate protocol to your viewcontroller .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Comment: i have put this in but nth seems to work still the same. this is what i put in for textFieldShouldReturn:
`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [tbMode resignFirstResponder];
    [tbWalkDist resignFirstResponder];
    [tbRouteOpt resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}`

Comment: Have you added the delegate protocol to your interface file?

Comment: Have you also created a delegate from your UITextField to your viewController (where the delegated method is)?

Comment: yup. i added `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>`

Comment: what else am i missing? or is the a way to take off the textfield completely?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly, but if you want this will hide the keyboard if you press return key :

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textFieldName resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
```

}

Comment: Edited the question. what i want to do is when click on the textfield only the picker view will be shown.

Comment: You can use a label instead of textField, and a button to show hide the picker view.

Comment: because i need 3 input which is from the text field